# Australia 417 working holiday visa: Can I contract to employer on my business ABN after visa full-time work rights expire?

Tags: visas, legal, australia, working-holiday, freelance

I'm really stuck and worried and wonder if any Australia visa gurus can advise. Any help is much appreciated.

**Facts:**

In Australia, on a 417 working holiday visa:

1. You can stay up to 12 months and you can work for an Australian company for up to 6 months.
2. After 6 months, you must give up the job, get a new visa or don't work at all.

**My situation:**

- Currently on a working holiday 417, I am employed full-time.
- No further visa options are available to me (I cannot apply for a new visa).
- I deliver a professional service to the business of which I am an employee. I have my own Australian business ABN, which also delivers that service.

**What I want to know is:**

1. Is it legal if, once my 6 months expires, that employer contracts to me via my own ABN, to do the same job but in a contract role vs. employed full time?
2. Surely if I have my own ABN, I can do contract work for anyone without limitation?

Comment: Do you mean a 417 visa? 407 is a training visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [webpage](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Work/Empl/WHM-six-months-one-employer) for this visa under the 'Meaning of One Employer' section says:

> You cannot stay in the same position in the same location with an
>   employer for more than six months by using different employment
>   agencies, business affiliates or sub-contracting arrangements.